# jQuery .clone() changes the reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of XML generated by jQuery.

### What I want

```
<booklists>
    <booklist>
        <userid>0</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
    <booklist>
        <userid>1</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
    <booklist>
        <userid>2</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
    <booklist>
        <userid>3</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
    <booklist>
        <userid>4</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
</booklists>
```

### What I get

```
<booklists>
    <booklist>
        <userid>0</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
    <booklist>
        <userid>4</userid>
        <userid>3</userid>
        <userid>2</userid>
        <userid>1</userid>
        <book>Foo</book>
        <book>Bar</book>
    </booklist>
</booklists>
```

### My code

```
lists = $('<booklists />')
books = $('<booklist />');

book = $('<book>Foo</book>');
books.append(book);

book = $('<book>Bar</book>');
books.append(book);

temp = books.clone();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    books.prepend('<userid>' + i + '</userid>');
    lists.append(books);
    books = temp;
}

$('.output').html(lists);
```

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/q6Q4A/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to move the `.clone()` call into the loop:

```
var lists = $('<booklists />'),
    books = $('<booklist />');
books.append('<book>Foo</book>').append('<book>Bar</book>');

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var temp = books.clone();
    temp.prepend('<userid>' + i + '</userid>');
    lists.append(temp);
}

$('.output').html(lists);
```

Btw, I don't think you should try to create XML nodes in an HTML document - it might not work in every browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, I use appjs (so don't care about browsers) and create a xml file with this code ;)

Comment: OK, just `$('.output').html(…)` brought me on the wrong track :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is because I wanted to show the results :)

Answer (score 3):

```
books = temp;
```

needs to be

```
books = temp.clone();
```